# iis 7.5 app pool recycling has irritating behaviour

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

Now I have one irritating problem. I have Site which includes many web apps on asp.net 2.0 classic app pool. My app works with the next steps: 
1) I recieve login form from server, input my credentials and send form. 
2) When credentials are correct, my server starts to merge all configuration settings from mashine.config and web.config to one file ApplicationConfiguration.merged.xml which located in app root folder. 
3) After that my app sends me page and I continue work with site. That's all.
But.. when I start my app first time after app_pool recycling(after time out or manual recycling) I have refreshing my app immediately after writing ApplicationConfiguration.merged.xml. After that my session is expired and I login again and my app works correctly.
ApplicationConfiguration.merged.xml locates in app root folder. When I switch off writing to this file or locate its to another folder (for example temp folder in app root folder) there all works correctly.
IIS refresh my app with next event:

```
Application_End
ChangeInGlobalAsax
_shutDownMessage=Overwhelming Change Notification in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_app_root_folder
Overwhelming Change Notification in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_app_root_folder
Change in GLOBAL.ASAX
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown
```

So as I understand IIS thinks that I have changed important configuration files(web.config of Glabal.asax) and refreshes my app. But I don't use this file for anything - I only write current configuration information here. And why doesn't IIS refresh app everytime when I am logging because I am writting file each time after succesfull login but IIS refresh my app only after firt start.
Can I say IIS to ingnore ApplicationConfiguration.Merged.xml changes? I believe you can help me to understand this curious IIS behaviour. Thank's for your help.

Comment: I solve this problem moving my files from root folder of web app to another problem. That's simple but that's work)